# The tilemap covers the floating text UNITY 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I want to display a floating text everytime the player opens a chest, that indicates how many coins you earned. I created the level using tilemaps. The problem arises when I created the floating text, basically it's covered by the tilemap, because if I move it out of the level I can see it, otherwise not. I tried fixing this problem by using layers, but I can't manage to make it work. Does anyone know how to help me?

[As you can see by the foto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg7LF.png) the outline of the text is visible, but in play mode you can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the order in layer in the tilemap renderer and set it to a negative value.Im sorry if it doesnt work I am new to unity.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).